# How to deal with an upload changing size after specifying the Content-Length?

Tags: python, content-length

I've come across a problem today, I'm uploading a multipart form with http POST using the [poster](http://atlee.ca/software/poster/) module.

Part of the form is a file, which poster streams up - which is great.

The problem I'm having is the `Content-Length` is calculated up front before the upload begins but because the form data is then generated dynamically it's entirely possible that amount of data that gets uploaded ends up being different (this is happening to me if the file in the form gets modified during the upload by something external).

If the file gets longer then the server will close the connection when it has received the amount of data specified in the content length before I've finished and I get a `Connection reset by peer` error. If the file gets shorter then the upload hangs up where the server is waiting for the rest of the bytes that I promised.

In the latter case I get this stack trace when I interrupt the hung upload:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/paul/Source/Python/test_uploader.py", line 35, in <module>
    gUpload(target_file, size, result.signed, callback, md5=md5)
  File "/Users/paul/Source/Python/PythonApp/upload.py", line 597, in handlingHttpError
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/paul/Source/Python/PythonApp/upload.py", line 663, in gUpload
    urllib2.urlopen(request)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 126, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 400, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 418, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 378, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/poster-0.8.1-py2.7.egg/poster/streaminghttp.py", line 142, in http_open
    return self.do_open(StreamingHTTPConnection, req)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1180, in do_open
    r = h.getresponse(buffering=True)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1030, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 407, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 365, in _read_status
    line = self.fp.readline()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 447, in readline
    data = self._sock.recv(self._rbufsize)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

How can I deal with this situation? I don't mind it throwing an error but this hang is killing me!

Comment: Either omit the `Content-Length` header altogether, or calculate the length up front. Which one you use depends on your code, but you didn't share any.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I thought it was required? and what do you mean by calculate the length up front?

Comment: It'd also be good to know what this "something external" is that is modifying files "during the upload".  That's not supposed to happen.

Comment: `Content-Length` is *not* required, but if it's there, the server is entitled to assume it's correct.  (It should send back a proper HTTP error code rather than just dropping the connection, though.)

Comment: @Zack something external just means not me, it could be any process that's editing the file in question- I don't think this is possible in windows because it locks the file, but it is unix

Comment: I do believe an error is the proper way of handling this. Changing a file during upload can lead to incorrect behaviour at best or may be a sign of security issues. Either way, your upload **should** crash and burn.

Comment: If you cannot control the uploaded data, create a copy first, *then* upload the copy instead. The Content-Length header is a promise to the server, and if you break that promise, you cannot reasonably expect things to work anyway.

Comment: @DJV I want an error, but if the file becomes shorter I get this infinite hang at the point in the traceback

Comment: Oh, I thought you meant something was modifying the data as it went over the network.  The quick-and-dirty way to snapshot a file that some other process might modify out from under you is to read the entire thing into memory and then use the observed size of the memory buffer to set `Content-Length`.  If the file is too big for that, `fcntl` locks *may* help, but it's not guaranteed.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't afford to put the file into memory, or assume the user has enough disk space to copy the file into

Comment: @GP89 haven't really worked with poster, but I suggest you look where you can add a timeout either on the server or in the client so it doesn't hang. Btw, is the server under your control or not?

Comment: @DJV No the server is not, I'm uploading to a google bucket. I thought about adding a timeout as this does wake up the `urlopen`, but I'm likely to introduce more problems - how do I pick a reasonable timeout? I could easily end up timing out slow uploads when I dont want to

Comment: @GP89 Well in that case, lock the file as Zack suggests. It's probably the cleanest approach of all of the above. Python doesn't support that natively, but there are some python libs for Linux/UNIX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the suggestions, however I can't afford to lock any files as my process is almost always going to be a lower priority than the process that may be editing the file I'm uploading.

This is what I went for in the end, it seems to work well!

```
class SizeCheckFile(file):
    def __init__(self, size, *args, **kwargs):
        file.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.size = size
        self.data_read = 0

    def read(self, *args, **kwargs):
        data = file.read(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.data_read += len(data)
        if self.data_read > self.size:
            raise UploadSizeMismatchError("File has grown!")
        elif not data and self.data_read != self.size:
            raise UploadSizeMismatchError("File has shrunk!")
        return data

    def seek(self, *args, **kwargs):
        current_pos = self.tell()
        file.seek(self, *args, **kwargs)
        if current_pos != self.tell():
            raise NotImplementedError("%s currently assumes the file is being read from start to finish!" % self.__class__.__name__)
```

The size I pass into the constructor is the same as the size I pass to poster for the `MultipartParam` `filesize` parameter.

Of course this assumes that no seeking is taking place, or I would have to override `seek` and keep track of exactly what's being read but for my use case I needn't worry as the file's being streamed out.